# Kubernetes LoadBalancer service not getting ELB external IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

LoadBalancer service in Kubernetes is not getting ELB external IP address as its stuck in pending state.

When immediately created it doesn't show any event logs but after a certain time it give the following error:

> Error syncing load balancer: failed to check if load balancer exists
> before cleanup: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain.
> Deprecated. For verbose messaging see
> aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

My definition are as follows,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv
    labels:
        app: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv-api
spec:
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run how many pods to run
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv-api
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/arch
                operator: In
                values:
                - amd64
                - arm64
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: <ecr_endpoint>/sample-graphql-fetcher-srv:0.2
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        imagePullPolicy: Always #IfNotPresent #
        env:
            - name: ENV_VAR
              value: 'Value'
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: sample-graphql-fetcher-srv-api
```

However the above definition works on a different cluster and it is providing with the elb endpoint immediately after creation.

I have checked the load balancer limits and elastic(static) IP limit but it had capacity. Also there are two other LoadBalancer Services with the elb endpoint that were created before.

Where can the problem lie on?

Comment: it looks like the node doesn't have the right IAM profile which prevents it from making AWS SDK calls, as evident by the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in the Trust relationship in the cluster's role not having the following,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```